# SwiftUI measuring creation time for each View

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am developing a SwiftUI MacOS app and I would like to measure the time for each view, that it needs till it is created/appear.

I came up with the approach starting the time in the `init()` method of the view and stop the time in the `didAppear()` method of my view.

```
var start : CFAbsoluteTime  

init()
{
    start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
}

var body: some View
{
    NavigationView
    {
        ...
    }.onAppear()
    {
        let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - self.start

        print("Took \(diff) seconds")
    }
}
```

This approach does work, but it is really time consuming adding this to all my view (probably more than 100). Is there a simpler solution, maybe any debug tool to activate?

Some of my view do need a longer time to load, maybe due to `@FetchRequest`, however I want to investigate which views do need the longest time. Maybe someone else has a better approach for SwiftUI.